# Override locals interface in typescript express server

Tags: typescript, express

I can override the locals interface inside express doing something like the following

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Locals {
      name: string;
      version: string;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is the type comes over as `Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>.locals: Record<string, any> & Locals` and the issue is the `Record<string, any>` which means that *anything* can be on that object. I cant quite seem how to figure out to drop the `Record<string, any>` so that the locals is always only what we want.

I also tried something like below which works great to read and autocomplete but when trying to write to the object its saying `type x is not assignable to never` even though I am writing the name as a string

```
declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  interface Locals {
    name: string;
    version: string;
    [key: string]: never;
  }
}
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.